# Linq Exception: Function can only be invoked from linq to entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `StudentReceipts` table which stores `ReceiptNo` as `string(001,002,003,..,099,..)`.

I want go get the last receiptno details inorder to increment the receiptno for next transaction.

This is what I have tried

```
  var _lastGeneratedRecDetails = _db.StudentReceipts
                                 .AsEnumerable()
                                 .Where(r => r.Status == true
                                             && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.DueDate.Value) >= _startDate.Date
                                             && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.DueDate.Value) <= _endDate.Date)                                                
                                            .OrderByDescending(x => Int32.Parse(x.ReceiptNo))
                                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

But there i am getting the following exception

> this function can only be invoked from linq to entities

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can fake numeric ordering by ordering by length and then by value. No need for any conversion.

Comment: By `Ordering by length` I think you meant `Ordering by Id` .If that is the case it does not work because there is a chance that last row may not have the `latest receiptno`

Comment: No, I mean `OrderByDescending(x => x.ReceiptNo.Length).ThenByDescending(x => x.ReceiptNo)`

Comment: I know I'm 3 years late but if someone is getting the same error, I resolved mine by changing `EntityFuncions` to a local function with `DbFunction` proxy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By calling `.AsEnumerable()` you are going from Linq-To-Entities to Linq-To-Object. By calling it, you are also filtering all the results in memory, so you are pulling the whole `StudentReceipts` table from the database everytime you do that query as it gets executed past the `.AsEnumerable()` method. The general rule is to try to do as much as you can on the database side:

```
var _lastGeneratedRecDetails = 
   _db.StudentReceipts.Where(r => r.Status == true
                       && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.DueDate.Value) >= _startDate.Date
                       && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.DueDate.Value) <= _endDate.Date)             
                      .AsEnumerable()                                   
                      .OrderByDescending(x => Int32.Parse(x.ReceiptNo))
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you do it like this, you will filter everything in the database and fetch the filtered results. I don't know what type `x.ReceiptNo` is though, but calling `Int.Parse` isn't allowed in Linq-To-Entities. You can filter first and then call `AsEnumerable` to be able to do the parsing and ordering in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate. But when i tried the above query i'm getting error `Value cannot be null`.When I changed `.OrderByDescending(x => Int32.Parse(x.ReceiptNo))` to `.OrderByDescending(x => x.ReceiptNo)` the query works.But still has doubt on how `descending` works on `string` values

Comment: @ksg You can try `OrderByDescending(x => x.ReceiptNo != null ? Int32.Parse(x.ReceiptNo) : 0)` with '0' as default value if it's null

Comment: Thanks mate it works.Forget that there could be a possibility of null .:)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was re-using a Func / Filter expression that included **DbFunctions.TruncateTime** in a follow-up processing statement AFTER I had already processed the query in SQL.  Removing it cleared the instance of the exception for me.

Answer (score 1):

use and 
`.AsQueryable()`

```
var _lastGeneratedRecDetails = _db.StudentReceipts
                             .AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why that error occurs, I remembered some DbFunctions working completely fine.
The reason is, that **not all DbFunctions are implemented in C# code**!

If you look at the "implementation" of `TruncateTime`
https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/255a32450db09a2feb07cb6199af1dcdfa189b8d/src/EntityFramework/DbFunctions.cs#L655

```cs
[DbFunction("Edm", "TruncateTime")]
public static DateTime? TruncateTime(DateTime? dateValue)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException(Strings.ELinq_DbFunctionDirectCall);
}
```

You can see why that error is thrown. It's just not implemented.

The code above basically says: execute the SQL-Function `TruncateTime`, if used in LINQ to Entities, and run the code (in this case: throw Exception), if used in LINQ to Objects

You can implement your own Method, just copy the code above in your own class, an replace your `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(.)` call with `MyFunctions.TruncateTime(.)`

That was really annoying to find. I needed this because sometimes the query will get run against the database, and sometimes only in code..

Of course, if you will only need to call that function against the database, you are completely fine with the solutions above