# This function can only be invoked by LINQ to Entities after Entity Framework update

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, entities

```
var messages = (from sms in
                (from m in rv.tbl_sms_messages
                where m.idtbl_user == ids.id
                where m.sms_date >= days.days7
                orderby m.sms_date descending
                select m)
                .Take(15)
                .AsEnumerable()
                    select new last10msgs 
                    { 
                        dat = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)SqlFunctions.DatePart("dd",sms.sms_date)) + " " 
                                + SqlFunctions.DateName("mm", sms.sms_date), message = sms.message 
                    }).AsEnumerable();
```

Got the error after updating from EF4 TO EF6+:

> This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Siavash This function can only be invoked by LINQ to Entities

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq Exception: Function can only be invoked from linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216647/linq-exception-function-can-only-be-invoked-from-linq-to-entities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have already done the DB operation when you try to use `SqlFunctions`. These functions have to be placed before running your query and storing the result into objects. After calling `AsEnumerable` your query is done. So the short answer is to move the logic which contains these functions to the query that runs against the DB (before the `Take` clause)