# Linq is not converting to SQL properly on runtime

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a simple LINQ query here but I get an exception

> function can only be invoked from LINQ to entities

Not to sure what it could be, I know it has to do with the SqlFunctions I am using but can't make out why. I have seen a prior solution to a similar issue but it does not apply for this scenario I believe ([This function can only be invoked by LINQ to Entities after Entity Framework update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59623549/this-function-can-only-be-invoked-by-linq-to-entities-after-entity-framework-upd)).

```
DateTime begin = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2022, 1, 1);

var dataSet = from e in _db.animals
              where e.age == 2 &&
                    SqlFunctions.DateDiff("yy",begin, end) < 2                                                        
              select e.AnimalType
```

Comment: How do you use `dataSet`?

Comment: Are you use Entity Framework? If so, it might be more approprate to use EntityFunctions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637317/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlfunctions-and-entityfunctions

Comment: Yes I am using entity framework. I tried using EntityFunctions as well but didn't have much luck with it as well. I am returning the dataSet as a jsonresult at the end -- return new JsonResult(dataSet.ToDataSourceResult(request))

Comment: It always important to mention the exact verion of entity framework. Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: That said, the predicate doesn't make sense because it doesn't depend on any queried database value. It's logically equivalent with `where e.age == 2 && true`.

Comment: `SqlFunctions.DateDiff("yy",begin, end)` compares the *variables*, not any table fields. That's what the error says. This clause isn't useful because its result is known without even running the query.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If used in the right environment, like EF6, this function works perfectly with local variables. Not that it makes sense, anyway.

Comment: @GertArnold that would mean that `_db` isn't a DbContext, or that `animals` isn't a `DbSet`. Perhaps an evil-repository-from-hell that returns an `IEnumerable<>` because "best practices" ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Likely, yes. And so we're waiting for OP's clarification before any answer addressing the *technical* issue is possible. I assume that the *logical* flaw is only an artifact because of abridging the code.

Comment: @user2785460 what are `_db` and `animals`? What is the *full* exception text, including the call stack? The error you posted will only be thrown if you try to use an EF function in LINQ to objects. Is the exception thrown inside `ToDataSourceResult` perhaps? Where does this method come from?

Comment: Hey @GertArnold you are right that this works well on EF6 and my current version is EF3. Is there a different way I should be doing this for EF3?

Answer (score 1):

It’s probably due to the fact that you’re calling the function using two local variables as parameters so it’s evaluating client side before querying the database, resulting in the error.

Comment: If used in the right environment, like EF6, this function works perfectly with local variables. It wouldn't harm to run a little test before posting a tentative answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Moho points out, both `start` and `end` are known, and don't need to be part of the query. Entity Framework is probably trying to evaluate the expression while compiling the query, rather than building it into the query. If this is really what you're trying to do, consider optimizing things by taking your expression out of the query.

```
DateTime begin = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2022, 1, 1);
int yearsDifference = end.Year - begin.Year;

var dataSet = from e in _db.animals
              where e.age == 2 && yearsDifference < 2                                                        
              select e.AnimalType;
```

Or further:

```
DateTime begin = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2022, 1, 1);
int yearsDifference = end.Year - begin.Year;

var dataSet = yearsDifference < 2
    ? Array.Empty<AnimalType>().AsQueryable()
    : from e in _db.animals
      where e.age == 2                                                       
      select e.AnimalType;
```

Comment: In that case, there's no reason to put `yearsDifference < 2` in the query, the result is already known.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Agreed. I added another example to indicate that. It seems like this is a strange use case, and there might be even more optimal ways to approach it.

Comment: As said above, in the right environment, like EF6, this function works perfectly well with local variables.